# Word for wanting a problem to be fixed

Tags: single-word-requests

Basically if a have a problem, a huge problem, and I really want it to be fixed, what is the word to describe how I'm feeling.

Comment: Only you can know the feeling you have. It would help if you provided more context...but maybe _frustration_? or _anxiety_?

Comment: Please add a sample sentence with a blank where the word would go, as is the requirement for the single-word-requests tag.

Comment: You are feeling a sense of urgency.

Answer (score 1):

[Afraid?](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk029A9CULe4O7mkuuDcgmaML3G_pOA%3A1610389718344&ei=1pj8X7q1FJWj1fAPrqO24A4&q=definition%20of%20afraid&oq=definition%20of%20afraid&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIMCCMQyQMQJxBGEPkBMgIIADIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yCAgAEBYQChAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoECAAQRzoFCAAQyQM6CQgjECcQRhD5AToHCAAQFBCHAjoECAAQClCB3wNYz-sDYK7tA2gAcAN4AIABqQSIAesRkgEHMy0xLjIuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi6-PGYwZTuAhWVURUIHa6RDewQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)

> "feeling fear or anxiety; frightened"

[Terror-stricken?](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/terror-stricken#:%7E:text=adjective,overwhelmed%20by%20terror%3B%20terrified.)

> "overwhelmed by terror; terrified"

[Aghast?](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk00zPwvfhHDK-60BkfzqiAXtX-heSA%3A1610388662876&ei=tpT8X6eCNcS61fAP0teV8AU&q=definition%20of%20aghast&oq=definition%20of%20aghast&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQyQMyAggAMgIIADIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgQIABBHOgkIIxAnEEYQ-QE6BAgjECc6CAgAEMkDEJECOgoIABDJAxBGEPkBOggIABAWEAoQHlDz-QFYwocCYKiJAmgAcAJ4AIAByAWIAYIYkgEJMy0yLjEuMi4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwintc2hvZTuAhVEXRUIHdJrBV4Q4dUDCA0&uact=5)

> "filled with horror or shock"

[Agitated?](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk03470G11Yz0p-Ls-E5ATl-knw_EsQ%3A1610388724884&ei=9JT8X-u8NbHT1fAPsMGw2Ao&q=definition%20of%20agitated&oq=definition%20of%20agitia&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgwIABDJAxANEEYQ-QEyBAgAEA0yBAgAEA0yBAgAEA0yBAgAEA0yBggAEA0QHjIICAAQDRAKEB4yBggAEA0QHjIGCAAQDRAeMgYIABANEB46BAgAEEc6CQgjECcQRhD5AToECCMQJzoFCAAQyQM6AggAOgoIABDJAxAUEIcCOgQIABAKOgUIABDLAToHCAAQyQMQClC3mgFYtaABYLirAWgAcAN4AIAB1ASIAaMXkgEFNC0zLjOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab)

> "feeling or appearing troubled or nervous"

[Petrified?](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk01kGqO5GOu68ymMnSVEFR2PLUvBgw%3A1610388699073&ei=25T8X5WJBOHlxgPH9qiwDA&q=definition%20of%20petrified&oq=definition%20of%20petrifi&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgoIABDJAxBGEPkBMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgQIABBHOgUIABDJAzoKCAAQyQMQFBCHAjoHCAAQFBCHAjoECAAQClCCnQFYjKgBYO60AWgAcAN4AYABuQSIAbUXkgEFNC0zLjOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab)

> "so frightened that one is unable to move; terrified"

As Cascabel said, only you can truly know how you are feeling.

Also, using a thesaurus next time would probably yield faster results.

Comment: Hi, @BreWoodsy. You could add the definitions of the terms.

Comment: Thanks, @niamulbengali. I'm not so sure if I defined the words in the correct format. Any further direction or help would be much appreciated. (:

Comment: You should see [Markdown Editing Help](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help). The norm is setting off a separate para with `>` for verbatim definitions. [Linking](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links) to the source is highly recommended. I suggest going to [the Frequent tab](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Frequent) and looking at the top questions and answers there for an idea.

Comment: Please take a look round the Help Center and at a few obviously thorough answers on ELU first, Bre, before worrying about how to format. Questions so open to interpretation are best left or close-voted on 'needs clarification' grounds; answering them invites further such questions. And questions answered obviously by  'afraid' + synonyms aren't at the level ELU prefers.